# In ant exec task can one supress the \t[exec] prefix added to all output from the child process?

Tags: ant

In ant when running a command with the exec task anything written to stdout or stderr in the child process has "    [exec] " prepended to every line written to both the console and the log file.  Is there a way to suppress this behavior or explicitly supply the prefix? (ie: to "" or maybe just an indent)

This is because an ant build run in an IDE the prefix scrambles the ability of the IDE to jump to source files by clicking on the output error messages from javac and other compilers

Answer (score 3):

You may run ant with `-emacs` option.

However in this case it will suppress the prefix for all tasks.

Otherwise you may implement your own log handler.

Comment: Hmm as ant is being run by the IDE I'm not sure I can put in the command line arg :| though for what I'm doing supressing it for all tasks would be appropriate.  In this case the only way to invoke an external command/script from the ide (intellij) is via ant but it pollutes the stdout prints in the log..

Comment: @peterk quick google shows how to set ant options for intellij https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/defining-ant-execution-options.html

Comment: @peterk If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you

Comment: Hmm but answer for me isn't useful in my context - I do upvote answers :) In my case ant is spawned by a non ant script run from ant, so the intelij settings don't have any effect. I sort of assumed voting for an answer indicates the "problem is solved" :)

Comment: @peterk I answered on several your questions. You didn't accept any. Do you think I will be motivated to look on your questions in future? Or are you expecting step-by-step solutions specifically adapted to your environment?

Comment: I didn't realize the checkmark is separate from the upvote. I looked back and I had upvoted all your answers except this one.

Comment: I just tried putting both '-e' and '-emacs' in the intellij build properties "ant command line" field, neither one suppressed the leading '   [exec]' on items printed in processes run by ant.

Answer (score 0):

In an interactive terminal on MacOS, I successfully sidestepped the Ant log-wrapping mechanism on the exec task by means of the `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` devices, as follows:

```
<exec executable="python" output="/dev/stdout" error="/dev/stderr">
    <arg line='myscript.py' />
</exec>
```

This will probably also work on Linux, though I havn't explicitly tested it.

On Windows it also works using `output="con" error="con"` (though in my case, tty codes from my script won't work in a Windows cmd terminal).